# How to calculate $\lim_{n\to ∞} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^n}{\cos x} dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Calculate $$\lim_{n\to ∞}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^n}{\cos x} dx$$

I stuck to check the sequence of function in this problem converge unformly or not

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$
\cos x\ge \cos 1>0,\quad \text{for $x\in [0,1]$},
$$
and hence
$$
\int_0^1\frac{x^n\,dx}{\cos x}\le\int_0^1\frac{x^n\,dx}{\cos 1}=\frac{1}{\cos 1}\cdot\frac{1}{n+1}\to 0.
$$

Answer (score 2):

One may observe that
$$
1-\frac{x^2}2 \le \cos x,\quad x \in [0,1],
$$ giving
$$
0\le\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^n}{\cos x} dx\le\int_{0}^{1} \frac{2x^n}{2-x^2 } dx=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{2x^n}{1+(1-x^2) } dx\le\int_{0}^{1} 2x^ndx=\frac2{n+1}
$$ which yields a limit equal to $0$ as $n \to \infty$, by the squeeze theorem.